# TestNG Not Finding Tests with Programmatic Call

Tags: java, testng

I have TestNG set to pick up some tests from an external Jar file.  The problem is that when I invoke the call, they don't actually run.

I'm doing this:

```
XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
suite.setName("Invoked Run");

XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
test.setName("Invoked Run");
test.setParallel(XmlSuite.ParallelMode.NONE);
test.setXmlPackages(Collections.singletonList(new XmlPackage("com.eln00b.*")));
test.setTimeout(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(300));

TestNG testNg = new TestNG();
testNg.setOutputDirectory(persisPath);
testNg.setXmlSuites(Collections.singletonList(suite));

URLClassLoader customClassLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(jarUrls);
testNg.addClassLoader(customClassLoader);

testNg.run();
int status = testNg.getStatus();
```

The status is always 8 (`HAS_NO_TEST`).

I know the Jars are in the class loader because I can run:

```
customClassLoader.loadClass("com.eln00b.MyTest");
```

HELP!!!!!

Comment: It's been a while since I looked into bare TestNG code but to me your code looks like your suite is empty even though you instantiated a `XmlTest` and added a package to it. Look here: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html They instantiate the test and pass the suite: `XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);`. Your test isn't referenced anywhere else.

Comment: @try-catch-finally same result :-(

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work-around my issue for now using the [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) library.  [This issue in TestNG](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1999) should get a sample project that performs the core issue of what is happening, but for what I need this works perfectly.  Here's the code I switched to in order to get things rolling:

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** I had to use Reflections 0.9.10 and **not** 0.9.11 (latest as of right now). I'll need to figure out what is wrong in that other version.

```
URLClassLoader customClassLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(jarUrls);
Optional<Class<?>> oTestClass = findClass("SomeCriteria", urlClassLoader);
Class<?> testClass = oTestClass.orElseThrow(IOException::new);

XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
suite.setName("Invoked Run");

XmlClass xmlClass = new XmlClass(testClass);

XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
test.setName("Invoked Run");
test.setParallel(XmlSuite.ParallelMode.NONE);
test.setXmlClasses(Collections.singletonList(xmlClass));
test.setTimeout(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(300));

TestNG testNg = new TestNG();
testNg.setOutputDirectory(persisPath);
testNg.setXmlSuites(Collections.singletonList(suite));

testNg.run();
int status = testNg.getStatus();
```

The logic for finding the class is pretty simple:

```
ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
configurationBuilder.setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forClassLoader(classLoader));
configurationBuilder.addClassLoader(classLoader);

Reflections reflections = new Reflections(configurationBuilder);
Set<Class<?>> scenarioClasses = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Test.class);

// filter classes here with criteria
```

I'll try and write something else that deals with [the bug](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1999) that is a full example but this gives me the answer to the problem specific to my issue that generated this question.